# ORA-01735 during running ALTER TABLE inside the body of a loop using Oracle EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: ora-01735

I am trying to use an ALTER TABLE statement inside the body of a cursor by using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <strAlterTableStatement>;` but i get `ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option` error. The statement is OK if i run it as a PLSQL statement but as a string passed to **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**, raises the error.

Comment: Please share more info. With the current info you can only be redirected to: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-01735%3A+invalid+ALTER+TABLE+option+error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a semi-colon at the end of the statement string.
Passing a statement to the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE must not include the semi-colon at the end of the command, otherwise Oracle raises the above error.

Running the below code would result to **ora-01735**

```
Begin
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT constraint1;';
end;
```

but running it without the semi-colon at the end of the statement string as below will work fine

```
Begin
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT constraint1';
end;
```